# Does Trampling allow you to attack many units in a row?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I was arguing with my DM over if the Trampling special ability allowed you to run over many units. I said that my summoned celestial elephant could run in a straight line and trample all units it runs over; my DM said I had to stop over the first I run over.

What's your take?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can run over multiple.

Looking at d20srd.org, the rules for [trampling](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#trample) state: *"The creature merely has to move over the opponents in its path"*.  The plural "opponents" is used several times in the description.

Line them up and mow them down :)

Also, there is no mention about being forced to stop prior to moving twice your speed for any reason.

Comment: Thank you. My rulebooks are in French and it's more ambiguous than that.

Answer (score 4):

As Pat notes, the Trample special ability allows you to make multiple such attacks per round; your DM may have been thinking of the Trample [*feat*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#trample), which is, of course, *totally unrelated* to the Trample special ability; it instead improves the [Overrun](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#overrun) special attack, which does *not* allow more than one use per round (even with the feat).

Comment: Nah, it really was the special ability. We've read the description out loud a few times.

Comment: ...I’d never noticed that. *sigh* Chalk another one up to wonderful editors at WotC.

Answer (score 1):

A mount can only trample once per turn. There is however a feat called cavalry charger in complete warrior that allows you to overrun multiple targets. See the entry for Fell Trample under the tactical feat cavalry charger. This is the rules for when you are mounted atop the beast.

Should you simply be trampling as an attack(which means the rider doesnt get an attack) the beast as a full round action travels twice its speed and overruns all targets in that line. should any targets only be partially be in the line, then they are allowed a reflex to avoid the trample.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. And once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)! You should make clear that you're talking about Trample the Mounted Combat feat, rather than Trample the monster special attack. (The two aren't related at all despite the identical name.)

Comment: I think this answer could benefit from making the distinction between the feat and the special ability more clear (see Burrito's answer).